# Best Method to Merge Javascript Arrays into an Object Literal

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, object-literal

I'm looking for a native JavaScript method to merge 2 arrays into a literal object.

Turn this:

```
var x = ["blue", "yellow", "red", "green", "brown", "grey", "gray", "orange"]; 
var y = ["james", "john", "robert", "michael", "william", "david", "richard", "wayne"];
```

Into this:

```
{
"obj" : {
    "blue" : "james",
    "yellow" : "john",
    "red" :  "robert", 
    "green" : "michael", 
    "brown" : "william", 
    "gray" : "david", 
    "grey" : "richard", 
    "orange" : "wayne"
  }
}
```

Comment: The arrays will always be of the same size?

Comment: _"I'm looking for..."_ - No, you're _asking_ for. [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @BrunoLM in theory the arrays will always be the same size unless something goes completely sideways.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for the link. Yes, I should have posted with source and where I was stuck. The bracket notation "obj[a[i]]" was something I completely overlooked. +1 for the good read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var x = ["blue", "yellow", "red", "green", "brown", "grey", "gray", "orange"]; 
var y = ["james", "john", "robert", "michael", "william", "david", "richard", "wayne"];

function merge2array(a, b) {
    var obj = {};
    var l = a.length;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        obj[a[i]] = b[i];
    }

    return obj;
}

var obj = merge2array(x, y);
console.log(obj);
```

This will return this object:

```
{
    "blue" : "james",
    "yellow" : "john",
    "red" :  "robert", 
    "green" : "michael", 
    "brown" : "william", 
    "gray" : "david", 
    "grey" : "richard", 
    "orange" : "wayne"
}
```

Then you can build your desired object:

```
var r = { obj: obj };
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a fairly simple loop:

```
var result = {obj: {}};
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    result.obj[x[i]] = y[i];
}
```

This assumes that `x` and `y` are always the same length. If they're not, you just need to add a bit more code for checking the lengths.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native method.

[Here you can find two ways of achieving it](http://jsfiddle.net/VyPyN/)

The first method, `m1`, will validate the length of your arrays, if it doesn't match it will throw an exception.

```
function m1(keys, values)
{
    // in case the arrays have different sizes
    if (keys.length != values.length)
        throw new Error("Arrays are not of the same size");

    var result = {};
    for (var i in keys)
    {
        result[keys[i]] = values[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

The second method, `m2`, will allow you to have more keys than values, and fill the missing values with null.

```
function m2(keys, values)
{
    // alternative handling for different sizes
    if (keys.length < values.length)
        throw new Error("You can't have more values than keys");

    var result = {};
    for (var i in keys)
    {
        var val = null;
        if (i < values.length)
            val = values[i];

        result[keys[i]] = val;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Both methods return an object, to have an object exactly as you described you will can do this:

```
var x = {};
x.obj = m1([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]);
```

For a [compact version](http://jsfiddle.net/deXmw/) (without validations) you can use:

```
function m(k,v){r={};for (i in k)r[k[i]]=v[i];return r}
```

Usage:

```
var x = { obj: m([1,2],["A","B"]) };
```

Change `m` to the desired function name.

**Reference**

- [Javascript objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)
- [Javascript arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp)
- [Javascript for/in loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)
- [Javascript errors](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)
- [Javascript Error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Answer (score 0):

fastest(using while--,caching length) / shortest way?

```
var a=['blue','yellow','red','green','brown','grey','gray','orange'],
b=['james','john','robert','michael','william','david','richard','wayne'],
c=[],d=a.length;while(d--)c[a[d]]=b[d];
var x={obj:c};
```

also as function (c&d are placeholder so you don't need to write var and save bytes)
the name of the function can be placed infront or after 'function'...whatever

```
function(a,b,c,d){c=[],d=a.length;while(d--)c[a[d]]=b[d];return c}
```